# Unit Testing Directive

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, gruntjs

I am having some problems with one of my unit tests. I was trying to test a directive, and I was trying to obtain a reference to the $compile provider into the unit test. I am using grunt with a specific package called grunt-contrib-testem to execute all unit tests.

Here's is a snippet of the configuration for such plugin(coffescript)

```
testem:
  unit:
    src: [
      "angular.js"
      "angular-mocks.js"
      "app.js"
      "directive.js"
      "spec.js"
    ]
    options:
      launch_in_dev: ["PhantomJS"]
      debug: true
```

and a snippet of the test case:

```
beforeEach(module("myapp"));

beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
    rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
    compile = $injector.get("$compile"); //<-here is the problem
}));
```

And the error message I am seeing is the following:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $windowsProvider <- $windows <- $http <- $compile
```

Many thanks.

Comment: you may not need to call the injector manually. one can just write beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile){ - but this is not the reason for the error. did you double check, that angular-mocks.js is available?

Comment: what i am missing is a line such this: beforeEach(module('myApp'));

Comment: sorry the beforeEach(module("myApp")); is included let me edit the post

Comment: I know that the call to the $injector is not needed. I did it to find what was happening.

Comment: next guess: did you use any template files? if so: you must include them via beforeEach(module('template.html')

Comment: no need for the template.html, the directive does not use a template.

Answer (score 0):

Try injection them this way

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}
```

Comment: Same as above:[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $windowsProvider <- $windows <- $http <- $compile